# Drill Across Functionality in Tabular Model

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, tabular, dimensional-modeling, star-schema

We've a Tabular model which has 3 facts and few dimensions.

Out of the 3 facts 2 are about Account & Products.

Facts realated to acocunt of a customer. How many are active, how much is the current balance, how much was the balance at the start etc.

Product Fact is about different supplement products that a cstomer has. He/she may or may not have a supplement product. Now this has facts like how much the customer owes in different products, rebate amount etc.

Now they both have Dimension Account as common Dim.

Relation between Account & Product is 1-M. If an account has supplement product it can be 1, 2 and max 3. If it doesnt have, it is 1-0 :)

Problem we're having is that if we want to slice both fact by Account Dim attribute, we get only the accounts which have supplement product. Becuase I believe Tabular model works on INNER JOINS. In this case I want to have OUTER JOIN. Since I'd want to have all accounts come through in the query and where i've matching supplement product then the fact for that products.

Any help is appreciated.